# In python, what is a "site" and why is there a directory called "site-packages"?

Tags: python

I am learning python and often see the word "site" used in the literature. However, I have been unable to locate a definition or explanation for the term.

1. What is a python "site"?
2. What does "site specific" mean?
3. Why does the "site-packages" directory have that name?

nota bene: I am not asking how the site-packages directory is used, just why it has that name.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: As in "installation *on-site*"…?

Comment: I have good news for you: you will be able to learn Python without solving this riddle.

Comment: I have the same confusion here too. Indeed, what does 'site' mean in python anyway?